# @current_user_sesssion) is working instead of @current_user_session in authlogic (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to Ruby on Rails using authlogic for user authentication and its working fine with the written code below

```
def current_user_session
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user_**sesssion**)

    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end
```

but not with the code

```
def current_user_session
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end
```

please pay your attention to spelling of session (in @current_user_session)

can anybody help about this whether this a logical error or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a small bug in your code. You want:

```
def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end
```

i.e. the variable you want to return is the one you've checked is defined `@current_user_session` and not `@current_user`.

The reason why the spelling mistake makes it work fine is because `defined?(@current_user_sesssion)` will always return false so that version of the method will always return the result of `UserSession.find`. With the correctly spelt `@current_user_session` then after the first call where `@current_user_session` becomes defined the method will be returning `@current_user` (which is probably `nil`).

Comment: Thanks mikej for pointing in right direction. This solves my problem.